# C++ sorting an index vector without lambda

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, lambda

I am trying to sort a vector of indexes, sorting it the same exact way as my regular vector is already sorted. This statement works correctly and compiles correctly in visual studio, but I need it to compile in Linux, so I need to somehow rewrite the statement to work with an older version of the compiler. The index vector is declared and initialized by this, which still works fine on the old compiler:

```
vector<float> indexes(toBeSorted.size());
//initialize original index locations
for (float i = 0; i != indexes.size(); ++i) indexes[i] = i;
```

The question is this line, which breaks in Linux:

```
sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [toBeSorted](float i1, float i2) {return toBeSorted[i1] > toBeSorted[i2]; });
```

Please help!

Comment: That line doesn't magically break in Linux unless it's doing something like invoking undefined behaviour. If you mean it doesn't compile, that's not Linux's problem.

Comment: which compiler are we talking about on Linux?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If GCC, try the `-std=c++0x` option to enable C++11 features.

Comment: You're using a lambda expression, which is C++11.  If your compiler is g++ 4.8 or newer, you can add the compiler flag `-std=c++11` to compile it directly.

Comment: @JoeZ, If you mean 4.8 for the flag, it works as of 4.7.1 if I'm not mistaken. Lambdas were supported long before that.

Comment: @chris: Yes, it could work with older versions.  I believe 4.8.x was the first where the GCC folks said C++11 support was "complete" (well, except for `regex`.)  You may need to use `-std=c++0x` to enable the experimental support in older versions, though, as opposed to `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @JoeZ, `<regex>` among other things. That was just the language part of it.

Comment: Why one earth is an array called `indexes` and used for indexing another array full of `float`s?

Comment: this is the error:  error: no matching function for call to âsort(std::vector<float>::iterator, std::vector<float>::iterator, sortAndOutput(std::vector<float>)::<lambda(float, float)>)â
main.cpp:108:121: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5394:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5430:5: note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)

Comment: Wait, how are you getting away with using a float as an index for an array? Unless it's actually a map or something...

Comment: @chris: A float is more likely to work as an array index than a map key, if you really think about it.  Array indices at least get implicitly cast back to integers.

Comment: @JoeZ, I'm fairly sure a float index for a built-in array is a sure compiler error. I know a map probably wouldn't work too well, but the other shouldn't compile :p

Comment: @chris:  For an actual array index, sure.  But for `operator[](int)` on a `vector<float>`, the compiler applies the type coercion.  Try it.

Comment: @JoeZ, Ah, I see. Sadly enough, I didn't even see that `size()` was called on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a functor:

```
struct Sorter
{
  bool operator()(...)
  { /* logic * / }
};
```

This should still work in an older version of the compiler...